# Ignore query string in URI segments with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, api, url, uri

I have the following URI:

```
/host/segment1[?parm1=value1&param2=value2]/segment2/segment3[?parm1=value1&param2=value2]
```

As you can see I would like to ommit the content inside the square brackets just like if it were:

```
/host/segment1/segment2/segment3
```

EDIT:The square brackets are just examples of the content I want to ommit, they do not actully appear in the segments.
A real examle would be:

```
/host/segment1?parm1=value1&param2=value2/segment2/segment3?parm1=value1&param2=value2
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a regular expression??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that with this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\?[^/]++~', '', $uri);
```

Details:

```
\?       question mark
[^/]++  all characters that are not a slash one or more times

~        used to delimite the regular expression
```

Comment: the square brackets are just examples of the content I want to ommit, they do not acutally appear in the segments.
A real examle would be:
/host/segment1?parm1=value1&param2=value2/segment2/segment3?parm1=value1&param2=value2